# How to use a nested loop in request.head - Node JS

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, request, fs

I am trying to move download images from parse and save it to my local. I have this piece of code that does the job for me. This works well when there is only one request but when I put in a loop, it doesn't hold good.

```
`for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log(i);//to debug
var filename = results_jsonObj[i].imageFile.name;
var uri = results_jsonObj[i].imageFile.url;
request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(item);
    return;
  }else {
    console.log(i); //to debug
    var stream = request(uri);
    stream.pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream("images/"+filename)
        .on('error', function(err){
          callback(error, filename);
          stream.read();
          })
      )
  }
});
}`
```

Irrespective of the loop condition I have, only one image downloads to the mentioned directory.

Below is the op

[image: the print logic is shown here]

The input is from a Json file and I have the request, fs, parse module included in the node js program.

Any help on how to go about this?

Comment: you can use async.js library for flow control, its really handy

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I'm going through the documentation. Any advice on how promises will be helpful though?

Comment: async are not promises. I prefer Async over promises.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this fixed now. As advised in the comments it was async which helped me do the trick.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
    async.forEachOf(results_jsonObj[i], function(value, key, callback){
    var image = {};
          image.key = key;
                image.value = value;
     if(image.key == 'imageFile')
    {
      var filename = image.value.name;
      var uri = image.value.url;
      // console.log(filename, uri);
    }

    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
        // console.log(item);
        return;
      }else {
        //  console.log(i,res.headers['content-type']); //to debug
        var stream = request(uri);
        stream.pipe(
          fs.createWriteStream("images/"+filename)
            .on('error', function(err){
              callback(error, filename);
              stream.read();
              })
          )
      }
    });
      callback();
    }, function(err){
      if (err) {
            console.log('one of the api failed, the whole thing will fail now');
        }
    });
    }
```